# running a query selecting 1 employee but results are generating multiple people

Tags: oracle

I'm running the following query but only wanted results for the one person (employeeid). The results are pulling multiple people and I cant determine what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Oracle SQL Dev

```
SELECT a.employeeid,
  TO_CHAR(a.startdtm, 'mm-dd-yyyy'),
  TO_CHAR(a.startdtm, 'hh24:mi'),
  TO_CHAR(a.enddtm, 'hh24:mi'),
  ((a.enddtm - a.startdtm) *24*60/60) "TOTAL",
  b.paycodename,
  (timeinseconds/3600)
FROM timesheetitem a,
  vp_timesheetitmv42 b
WHERE b.employeeid = '15642'
AND (a.startdtm    = b.startdtm
AND timeinseconds IS NOT NULL)
OR a.startdtm      = b.startdtm
AND a.EVENTDTM 
 BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013', 'dd-MON-YYYY') 
 AND TO_DATE('31-MAR-2013', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
```

Comment: Please format that SQL so it's actually readable

Answer (score 0):

You have an "or" statement next to your `b.employeeid = '15642'` which means it's going to bring back more than just that employee, most likely. Use parentheses:

Before:

```
where b.employeeid = '15642'
and (a.startdtm = b.startdtm and timeinseconds is not null)
or a.startdtm = b.startdtm
and a.EVENTDTM between TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013', 'dd-MON-YYYY') and  TO_DATE('31-MAR-2013', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
```

After:

```
where b.employeeid = '15642'
and ((a.startdtm = b.startdtm and timeinseconds is not null)
    or a.startdtm = b.startdtm
    and a.EVENTDTM between TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013', 'dd-MON-YYYY') and  TO_DATE('31-MAR-2013', 'dd-MON-yyyy'))
```

Comment: It looks like you are probably missing parentheses elsewhere but that's not the question you asked so I'll let you fix those yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle master, but taking a look at:

```
and (a.startdtm = b.startdtm and timeinseconds is not null) 
or a.startdtm = b.startdtm
```

In my humble opinion, the `OR` condition, produces the undesired value. For me the previous condition, is equal to:

```
and (a.startdtm = b.startdtm)
```

I think this should do the job:

```
where 
    b.employeeid = '15642' 
    and (a.startdtm = b.startdtm) 
    and a.EVENTDTM between TO_DATE('01-JAN-2013', 'dd-MON-YYYY') 
                            and  TO_DATE('31-MAR-2013', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
```